# replacing two words strings with other two words not working

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I get some string from the internet in the format like "light rain" and so on, no i want to "translate" this string to other languages but if i try something like:

```
get
        {
            return description.replace("light rain", "111 222")
                              .replace("light snow", "333 444");
        }
```

i get the result "light bla" instead of "bla bla", so the first word is somehow not translated. is there any other way of getting "hard coded" strings translated to other languages in an Windows Phone 8 app?!

i have changed the code to make it more clear. above you see that i need more strings to be replaced but every string has its own meaning in the other language so fo rthe word light i have two different words i must replace, and not just one. Therefore the 333.

This code however gives me every time "light 222" but it doesnt replace the light.

it worked with the method underneath. i just used it like this:

```
            string sentence = "light rain";
            string pattern = "light rain";
            Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
            string translation = "lagana kiša";
            string result1 = reg.Replace(sentence, translation);

            var result = description
                .Replace("light rain", result1)
```

And it should actually work with even more complex strings and sentences. thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve your problem with multiple "light" words you should use regular expression to replace just "light rain" with "bla bla"

here is a some test case in console app:

```
string sentence = "light light light rain rain bla";
string pattern = "light rain";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
string translation = "bla bla";
string result = reg.Replace(sentence, translation);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

the result will be `"light light bla bla rain bla"`

Comment: that is good but doesnt help either. let me explain so i need to translate "light rain" and i get "lagana kiša" but the next string i get is "light snow" but i cant use again lagana becaue it should be "blagi snijeg" in english its one word but i need to get with every string i get an another translation (replace).

then i end up with something like this .replace("light rain", ""lagana kiša).replace("light snow", "blagi snijeg"). but ther is an problem and often it dont recognize the second string anymore i get snow translated (replaced) but not light in this second string.

Comment: And then again how to use your method with about 100 strings i have to translate?!

Answer (score 0):

```
get
        {
            var result = description.replace("light rain", "bla bla");
            return result;
        }
```

Read more about `string replace` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That doesnt work because it does the same thing like my code above. the problem i think is i have after this string more with light in it but it gives it an another meaning.

so i have something like .replace().replace().replace() with a lots of strings, some of them are larges, even sentences. and i some of them there is the word light. which is then not translated. and i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that the substitution is Case sensitive while your string differ on such.